# Does Cloud SQL Postgres have any cron-like tool?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I would like to use Cloud SQL with PostgreSQL with an internal cron-like tool. In the extensions list I can't find anything like that.

Do you know any solution/alternative which wouldn't include having an extra Compute Engine instance from where we can make calls ?

Comment: As I understand you are asking to recommend a library, sadly this is off-topic for Cloud SQL. Otherwise it might be that I am misunderstanding what you are asking.

Comment: I would like to know a solution to use cron-like tool inside of Cloud SQL(like every 1min to make some select/insert in Cloud SQL without external API).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run cron internally in Cloud SQL as it is [fully managed](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/) and you only get the access to the database itself.

#### Workaround

If you need to run this inserts and selects each minute then you can use [Google's Task queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) to send a request to an App Engine service that will do all that.

```
cron:
    - description: "make some select/insert"
      url: /tasks/populate
      schedule: every 1 mins
      target: populate_postgres
```

You have [28 free instance hours](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Instances) a day to use with App Engine instances.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** run cron internally in Cloud SQL thanks to [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) extension [support](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#miscellaneous-extensions) added on [November 19, 2021](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/release-notes#November_19_2021).

> `pg_cron` - Provides a cron-based job scheduler. This extension enables cron syntax to schedule PostgreSQL commands directly from the database. For more information about the extension, see the [pg_cron](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#pg_cron) section.
> Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL uses version 10 (or higher).

```bash
gcloud sql instances patch INSTANCE_NAME --database-flags=cloudsql.enable_pg_cron=on
```

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;

-- Delete old data on Saturday at 3:30am (GMT)
SELECT cron.schedule(
          'delete outdated events',
          '30 3 * * 6', 
          $$ DELETE FROM events WHERE event_time < now() - '1 week'::interval $$
       );
```