# Is there way to use pg_cron from the google cloud sql?

Tags: java, postgresql, google-cloud-sql, spring-cloud-gcp

Currently I need to move my database from  postgreSql to google cloud sql. I use pg_cron to remove stale records like this:

```
SELECT cron.schedule('30 3 * * 6', $$DELETE FROM events WHERE event_time < now() - interval '1 week'$$);
```

I've read folowing article: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions

And was not found anything related to pg_cron

Also I've read [Does Cloud SQL Postgres have any cron-like tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609087/does-cloud-sql-postgres-have-any-cron-like-tool) but it looks like overengineering for my task.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `pg_cron` is not supported by Cloud SQL. In order to be able to run this extension you need to do it as `SUPERUSER`. As mentioned in the post you found Cloud SQL is a fully-managed service. This means that while some operations such as seting up, maintain, managing and administering your databases are managed easily, you don't have the [SUPERUSER privilege](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users#default-users).

There is an open [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/79668909) regarding this improvement but there is no estimated time of arrival for this.

If the workaround given in the same post is not suitable for you, you can always create a [Compute Engine VM instance and set up PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres) there. This will allow you to fully manage your database.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Note that pg_cron does not require superuser. The managed service only needs to GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA cron to the main database user. Various managed services support pg_cron.

Answer (score 6):

As of November 2021 pg_cron is available:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/release-notes#November_19_2021

Flags to enable and configure pg_cron available in following link

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags